# Use IPA symbols conflict with \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am using a style that uses `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` and cannot be changed because other users need this command.

I want to use some IPA symbols (e.g. with the font "Doulos SIL") in my document.

When I use the following in combination with `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` the IPA symbols are not shown. If I remove the `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` the fonts are shown.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% the following is imported via mystyle
% \usepackage{mystyle}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}
ʃɛɔʊ
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

How can I use/show IPA symbols?

We use Xelatex

Comment: `\fontspec{Doulos SIL}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `\setmainfont` in the document body.

You can rather define a font family for Doulos SIL

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\doulos}{Doulos SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textdoulos}{\doulos}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

Some text \textdoulos{ʃɛɔʊ} and some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you give a hint/link on why not to use `\setmainfont` in the document body?

Comment: @wolfrevo I can think to very particular documents that have two different main fonts, but that’s not your case. You have a single main font, like the vast majority of documents and some secondary ones. The `\setmainfont` command has to do quite a job, and it’s really inefficient. Besides, should you realize that Doulos is not the best choice, would you prefer to chase the document or just change the font name in `\newfontfamily`?

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Even if we use many different fonts because our documents have linguistics examples in different languages (chinese, arabic, etc.), you are right: We use a single main font. We switch font only for the examples. It makes sense!